# Rails using Redis as session store with Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redis

I have just switched from using cookie as session store to redis.
The configuration is as below:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'redis-rails', group: :production

# config/initializers/session_store.rb
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, redis_server: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'], expires_in: 60.minutes
else
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_marketplace_session'
end
```

However, I remember that when setting up unicorn, I have to take care of external connection.
This is an example of Resque

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = ENV['<REDIS_URI>']
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end
end
```

Do I also have to disconnect and reconnect from Redis in Unicorn config? I only use Redis as session store and nothing else.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As redis-store uses redis-rb, you need to create the connection after Unicorn forks. So you have to do something similar to what you do with Resque if the connection is already open.

Here's a code example:

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Anything else you may have
  # ...

  Rails.cache.reconnect
end
```

That call to reconnect will make sure each process uses its own Redis client.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: The code example reconnects the cache_store when the question asks how to reconnect the session_store.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I have this same issue with Redis session_store, has anyone come up with a solution?? Thanks!